# Javascript Graph not showing in body but showing in Head

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvasjs

I'm trying to create a 'dashboard' with 4 graphs in a 2x2 table formation. I can get the graphs to display in the `<head>` section of the page but not in the `<body>`. I am doing what canvasJS instruct, but cannot get it working. I am just using 4 sample graphs to test it for now

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<div id="chartContainer1" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;float:left;"></div> 
<div id="chartContainer2" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> </br>
<div id="chartContainer3" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;float:left;"></div>
<div id="chartContainer4" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>

<script>
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1",
    {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Spline Area Chart"
        },
        axisX: {
            interval: 10,
        },
        data: [
        {
            type: "splineArea",
            color: "rgba(255,12,32,.3)",
            type: "splineArea",
            dataPoints: [
                { x: new Date(1992, 0), y: 2506000 },
                { x: new Date(1993, 0), y: 2798000 },
                { x: new Date(1994, 0), y: 3386000 },
                { x: new Date(1995, 0), y: 6944000 },
                { x: new Date(1996, 0), y: 6026000 },
                { x: new Date(1997, 0), y: 2394000 },
                { x: new Date(1998, 0), y: 1872000 },
                { x: new Date(1999, 0), y: 2140000 },
                { x: new Date(2000, 0), y: 7289000 },
                { x: new Date(2001, 0), y: 4830000 },
                { x: new Date(2002, 0), y: 2009000 },
                { x: new Date(2003, 0), y: 2840000 },
                { x: new Date(2004, 0), y: 2396000 },
                { x: new Date(2005, 0), y: 1613000 },
                { x: new Date(2006, 0), y: 2821000 }
            ]
        },
        ]
    });
chart.render();

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2",
    {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Pie Chart",
        },
        data: [
        {
            type: "pie",
            showInLegend: true,
            dataPoints: [
                { y: 4181563, legendText: "PS 3", indexLabel: "PlayStation 3" },
                { y: 2175498, legendText: "Wii", indexLabel: "Wii" },
                { y: 3125844, legendText: "360", indexLabel: "Xbox 360" },
                { y: 1176121, legendText: "DS", indexLabel: "Nintendo DS" },
                { y: 1727161, legendText: "PSP", indexLabel: "PSP" },
                { y: 4303364, legendText: "3DS", indexLabel: "Nintendo 3DS" },
                { y: 1717786, legendText: "Vita", indexLabel: "PS Vita" }
            ]
        },
        ]
    });
chart.render();

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer3",
    {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Line Chart"
        },
        axisX: {
            valueFormatString: "MMM",
            interval: 1,
            intervalType: "month"
        },
        axisY: {
            includeZero: false
        },
        data: [
        {
          type: "line",
          dataPoints: [
              { x: new Date(2012, 00, 1), y: 450 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 01, 1), y: 414 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 02, 1), y: 520, indexLabel: "highest", markerColor: "red", markerType: "triangle" },
              { x: new Date(2012, 03, 1), y: 460 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 04, 1), y: 450 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 05, 1), y: 500 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 06, 1), y: 480 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 07, 1), y: 480 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 08, 1), y: 410, indexLabel: "lowest", markerColor: "DarkSlateGrey", markerType: "cross" },
              { x: new Date(2012, 09, 1), y: 500 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 10, 1), y: 480 },
              { x: new Date(2012, 11, 1), y: 510 }
            ]
        }
        ]
    });
chart.render();

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer4",
    {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Column Chart"
        },
        axisX: {
            interval: 10,
        },
        data: [
        {
            type: "column",
            legendMarkerType: "triangle",
            legendMarkerColor: "green",
            color: "rgba(255,12,32,.3)",
            showInLegend: true,
            legendText: "Country wise population",
            dataPoints: [
                { x: 10, y: 297571, label: "India" },
                { x: 20, y: 267017, label: "Saudi" },
                { x: 30, y: 175200, label: "Canada" },
                { x: 40, y: 154580, label: "Iran" },
                { x: 50, y: 116000, label: "Russia" },
                { x: 60, y: 97800, label: "UAE" },
                { x: 70, y: 20682, label: "US" },
                { x: 80, y: 20350, label: "China" }
            ]
        },
        ]
    });
chart.render();
    </script>


    <style>
        #page {
        margin: 5% 10% 0% 10%;
        font-family: "Century Gothic";
        font-weight: lighter;
        }

        #header {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        font-weight: 100;
        text-align:left;
        padding:5px;
        }

        #nav {
        line-height: 50px;
        background-color: #707070;
        height: 100%;
        width: 10%;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px; 
        }

        #section {
        margin-left: 1%;
        background-color: #A8A8A8;
        height: 100%;
        width: 85%;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px; 
        }

        #footer {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        clear: both;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 5px; 
        }

        a {text-decoration: none; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px 5px 10px 4px;}
        a:link    {color:orange; background-color:transparent}
        a:visited {color:orange; background-color:transparent}
        a:hover   {color:orange; background-color:#D8D8D8}
        a:active  {color:orange; background-color:transparent}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header">
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="nav" align="center">
        <a href="dashboard.html">Dashboard</a><br>
        <a href="sales.html">Sales</a><br>  
        <a href="products.html">Products</a><br>
        <a href="customers.html">Customers</a><br>
        <a href="referrals.html">Referrals</a><br>  
        </div>

        <div id="section">
        <table style="width:100%; height:100%;" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>Daily Sales<div id="chartContainer1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;float:left;"></div></td>
                <td>New and Returning Customers<div id="chartContainer2" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> </br></td>     
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Popular Products<div id="chartContainer3" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;float:left;"></div></td>
                <td>Revenue by Product Category<div id="chartContainer4" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
        <p> Footer </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: UM, why do you have div tags in the head?

Comment: Normal "Head" section of a page is never rendered by any browser... So it is very unclear what you mean " I can get the graphs to display in the <head> section". (Also I suspect @epascarello comment explains that your "head" is not really considered "head" but possibly yet another broken page...)

Comment: Do you have any idea why the graphs display when I put them in the head then? and not in the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERRORS

```
1.div tags in the head
2.In-proper tags in tables
3.Un-necessary `</br>` tags // which can be solved through `CSS`
```

**Refer this working fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/gjfqzyc5/

`#ID` is unique.

**if you use same id in multiple places in same page it will not affect.**

http://jsfiddle.net/gjfqzyc5/6/

Comment: Thanks, The only way I can get the graphs to display is to put those divs (that are supposed to be in the body) in the head. Do you know why they will display in the head but not the body?

Comment: I must be doing something completely wrong because I've copied your code and the space is being made for the graphs but they're just not displaying

Comment: Yeah, I have. Does the <script> part where the graphs are actually made go in the head aswell?

Comment: Jsfiddle or the actual page?

Comment: Here it is, thanks so much http://spider.science.mq.edu.au/mqauth/42910366/ass2/piegraphtest.html

Comment: `var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(\"chartContainer1\", `error in console why this`\"chartContainer1\ ` lines added here. Go to the fiddle copy js part add repalce the js in your project and let me know.

Comment: replace the javascript  in script tag it will work ok

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure which section you mean? and what i replace it with?       EDIT - Oh the / are in there because I need it in PHP in another file

Comment: Okay, I exported the JS fiddle file and got it working, but for some reason I can't get the right-hand-side Navbar working anymore?

Comment: make height 100%; #section {
height: 100%;
}

Comment: I've got it showing now, if you have a look it's there :) The only issue now is that it's not the entire height of the page

Comment: quick fix will be #nav {
height: 652px;}

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64172/discussion-on-answer-by-manjunath-siddappa-javascript-graph-not-showing-in-body).